# Using Hibernate with H2 database and joda DateTime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jodatime, h2

I'm using Hibernate with the H2 in-memory database.
The database tables are automatically created based on the beans information I've provided in the persistence.xml file.

H2 is mapping a field called "created" of type **org.joda.time.DateTime**
to a column of type **VARBINARY(255)**

When I try to persist my bean with the value `created=DateTime.now()`, I get the following error:

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "CREATED BINARY(255)": "X'aced0005737200166f72672e6a6f64612e74696d652e4461746554696d65b83c78646a5bddf90200007872001f6f72672e6a6f64612e74696d652e62617365... (273)";  
    SQL statement:  
    insert into mytable (id, created) values (null, ?) [22001-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
```

Any idea why and what I can do to solve it?
Unfortunately I can't change the bean definition, so I have to keep using the joda DateTime.

Thank you!

P.S. This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="my-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>com.model.MyTable</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/c:\UnitTest;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS UnitTest" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

And the table automatically generated by Hibernate / H2:

```
MYTABLE
    ID BIGINT(19) NOT NULL
    CREATED VARBINARY(255)
```

And this is my bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class MyTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "created")
    private DateTime created;

    public DateTime getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setCreated(DateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public MyTable() {
    }

    public MyTable(DateTime created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your mapping table?

Comment: Hi Jon, do you want to see the bean, the generated H2 SQL table or the persistence.xml?

Comment: The persistence.xml file - just the relevant part. (If you could create a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem, that would be ideal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a demonstration (and explanation) of your problem:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(new DateTime());
oos.close();
System.out.println("Serialized size: " + bos.toByteArray().length); // output: 273
```

So a `DateTime`-object needs 273 bytes when serialized to a byte array. And since the column type does accept byte-arrays, but is configured to only accept as maximum 255 bytes, you get the SQL-exception. There is only one way to solve the problem if you want to keep JodaTime and the byte-array-storage-mechanism: Increase the column size to at least 273 (needs editing of `persistence.xml`).

EDIT: Is it possible for you to reconsider the storage mechanism? The column type VARBINARY seems not to be the best choice because of its size (and you cannot even apply comparing operators in SQL on this type). Alternatives are VARCHAR (but only in ISO-8601-notation please) or SQL-TIMESTAMP. Watch especially for this [Joda-Hibernate-support](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) in order to use Type-annotations and better column types.

Comment: This. If you can't edit the bean definition, change the database schema. TIMESTAMP is a much more suitable DB type for storing timestamps than VARBINARY anyway. Oh, also unless you're using Java 8, you will be glad you're using Joda-Time. :)

Comment: Just to note: JDK-GregorianCalendar even needs catastrophic 2385 bytes!!! So JodaTime is much better. And JSR-310 (and my library) are further improved in serialization behaviour (around 100? bytes - cannot actually test).

Comment: Thank you Meno, this is a great explanation. The storage mechanims (i.e. VARBINARY) is generated automatically by Hibernate/H2. I guess I can specify the DB tables manually, but I have around 100 of them... so I was hoping for a workaround or a way to tell Hibernate to translate the joda DateTime differently.

Comment: @user1005007 Hibernate appears to automatically generate VARBINARY column because the joda-type is not directly supported. I would suggest you to try Hibernate-Type-annotation - see the new link in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Meno, that would be great if I could edit the beans/entities, which I'm not allowed to. However I've found a way to write the automatically generated Database schema to a file, so from there I should be able to edit the VARBINARY and force Hibernate to use that one... I hope :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Joda-Time-Hibernate mapping:

> @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")

Answer (score 0):

You can mapping the CREATED column length on the MYTABLE.groovy domain:

```
static mapping = {
    CREATED column: "CREATED", sqlType: "VARBINARY", length:273 }
```